# Android Beam: Sending message to only specific application

Tags: android, nfc, android-beam

I am developing one application which uses Android Beam.

Can we send message through Beam which only gets delivered to the same application ? No other app would be able to receive that, not even device's default NFC reader application !!

If you have solution, please let me know.

Comment: Did you check out android application records?

Comment: Yes I did. But when the application is not installed it opens the Google Play. My requirement is if application is not installed then no one will receive the message and sender will get unsuccessful send operation callback. Is it possible ??

Comment: No that seems not possible using the push APIs. But you could always use an out-of-band approach like the remote app confirming 'message recieved' over bluetooth or wifi.

Comment: So for acknowledgement we will have to use another medium than NFC. And in that case it will require pairing/authenticating. So it takes away the NFC advantage..:(  But thanks for the reply Thomas !!

Comment: yes, android beam only allows information to go one way.

to your original point - I'm not sure the intent delivery system as a whole has a callback for a failed delivery...